# Dependency Injection, ASP.NET MVC, Ninject: Binding certain implementations to certain controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

Assuming that I have two controllers which use the same interface in their constructors like:

```
public class XController: Controller{

   private IOperation operation;
   public XController (IOperation operation){
      this.operation = operation;
   }

   public ActionResult Index(){
       ViewBag.Test = operation.Test();
       return View();
   } 
}

public class YController: Controller{

   private IOperation operation;
   public YController (IOperation operation){
      this.operation = operation;
   }

   public ActionResult Index(){
       ViewBag.Test = operation.Test();
       return View();
   } 
}
```

And

```
public interface IOperation {
    String Test();
}
public class Implementation1: IOperation{
    String Test(){retrun "Implementation 1";}
}
public class Implementation2: IOperation{
    String Test(){retrun "Implementation 2";}
}
```

When using Ninject, I can do `kernel.Bind<IOperation>().To<Implementation1>()` and this changes the behavior for both my X and Y controllers. However, I sometimes may need to bind my X controller to Implementtaion1 while leaving my Y controller still bind to Implementation 2.
Is this possible at all without having to separate Implementation 1 from Implementation 2 completely by defining a new interface?

Comment: What happens to the controllers when you swap implementations? Do those controllers depend on the actual implementation? If that's so, you are violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If this is the case, you should each implementation its own unique interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional/[contextual bindings](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) like so:

```
Bind<IOperation>().To<Implementation1>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<Controller1>();

Bind<IOperation>().To<Implementation2>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<Controller2>();
```

Note, that then `WhenInjectedInto` constraint checks for the type it is *directly* injected into. There's some other built-in constraints as well, and of course you can also write your own using the `When(...)` method.